# unable to get spinner value on android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I am trying to show the spinner value on a textview when I click on it. the current spinner array value is retrieved from firebase. when i click the dropdown, I am able to see the different selection on the spinner. however when i click on any of the selection, my textview did not show the value same goes to the spinner value.

```kotlin
  
    lateinit var managernames: ArrayList<String>
    editleaveview = findViewById(R.id.EditLeaveTypeTextView)
    managernames= ArrayList()

    editleavespinner = findViewById(R.id.EditSelectLeaveTypeSpinner)
    getManagername()

    val arrayAdapter =
        ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, managernames)

    editleavespinner.adapter = arrayAdapter
    editleavespinner.onItemSelectedListener =
    object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
            editleaveview.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
            Log.d("nothing", "test")
        }

        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {

            editleaveview.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)


            editleaveview.text = editleavespinner.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
        }
    }

    fun getManagername() {

        managerdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Leavetype")
        managerdatabase.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                for (names in snapshot.children) {
                    managernames.add(names.child("type").value.toString())
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: `val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,managernames)
        editleavespinner.adapter = arrayAdapter` should be in the onDataChange()

Comment: i tried putting it into onDataChange() but there is error on ArrayAdapter

Comment: I found the issue regarding this. jus by changing the this to applicationContext

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding `.notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter after getting the value.

```kotlin
      fun getManagername() {
                managerdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Leavetype")
                managerdatabase.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        
                        for (names in snapshot.children) {
                            managernames.add(names.child("type").value.toString())
                        }
                       arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    }
        
                    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                        TODO("Not yet implemented")
                    }
                })
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

in your onItemSelected() method just change this

```
editleaveview.text = editleavespinner.getSelectedItem().toString()
```